# What is the most efficient way to reinterpret underlying bit patterns and write it into and array or field?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, unsafe, reinterpret-cast

Using `Unsafe.putXXX` one can put primitive type into an array or object field.

But code like the following generate errors.

```java
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    VarHandle varHandle = MethodHandles.arrayElementVarHandle(long[].class);

    byte[] array = new byte[32];

    printArray(array);
    varHandle.set(array, 1, 5);
    printArray(array);

    System.out.println(varHandle.get(array, 1));
  }

  private static void printArray(byte[] array) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
  }

}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [B to [J
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3780)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Also the `bytes` may be write as:

```java
byte[] array = new byte[32];
long v = 5,
int i = 8;
int high = (int) (v >>> 32);
int low = (int) v;
array[i + 0] = (byte) (high >>> 24);
array[i + 1] = (byte) (high >>> 16);
array[i + 2] = (byte) (high >>> 8);
array[i + 3] = (byte) high;
array[i + 4] = (byte) (low >>> 24);
array[i + 5] = (byte) (low >>> 16);
array[i + 6] = (byte) (low >>> 8);
array[i + 7] = (byte) low;
```

Is there an efficient way to write reinterpret different types and write them into fields and arrays possibly avoiding `Unsafe` but as efficient.

Any special cases where the compiler or JIT will recognise the intent and optimise accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `byte[]` in particular you can use `MethodHandles::byteArrayViewVarHandle`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VarHandle varHandle = MethodHandles.byteArrayViewVarHandle(long[].class,
                                                               ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    byte[] array = new byte[32];

    printArray(array);
    varHandle.set(array, 1, 5);
    printArray(array);

    System.out.println(varHandle.get(array, 1));
}

private static void printArray(byte[] array) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

---

There are some hoops you have to jump through with VarHandles to make them just as fast as Unsafe;

1. Make sure the VarHandle itself is constant, this can be done by putting it in a static final field and accessing it from there.
2. Make sure the VarHandle invocation is exact. Here this would mean
   casting the second argument to a long since the VarHandle excepts a
   long as well. (in the latest JDK you can use `VarHandle::withInvokeExactBehavior` to enforce that).

This could be made easier by wrapping the VarHandle set and get calls in  helper methods that do the cast:

```
private static final VarHandle LONG_ARR_HANDLE 
        = MethodHandles.byteArrayViewVarHandle(long[].class,
                                               ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

public static void setLong(byte[] bytes, int index, long value) {
    LONG_ARR_HANDLE.set(bytes, index, value);
}   

public static long getLong(byte[] bytes, int index) {
    return (long) LONG_ARR_HANDLE.get(bytes, index);
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. What is the performance in relation to use of `Unsafe`? Is this as efficient or is this the most performant way to do this?

Comment: There are some hoops you have to jump through with VarHandles to make them just as efficient as Unsafe; 1) Make sure the VarHandle itself is constant, this can be done by putting it in a `static final` field and accessing it from there. 2) Make sure the VarHandle invocation is exact. Here this would mean casting the second argument to a `long` since the VarHandle excepts a `long` as well. This could be made easier by wrapping the VarHandle set call in a helper method that does the cast.

Comment: What is the array is not `byte[]`? Say `long[] array` and I want to write `byte`.

Comment: If the array is not a `byte[]` you would have to use the memory access API which is incubating in the latest JDK (16). There you can convert the `long[]` into a `MemorySegment` and then access it using a `byte` memory access VarHandle.

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way, using `ByteBuffer`, is also the fastest way as of Java 17. Measure for yourself (and/or consider other options) if you're not on Java 17 yet.

```java
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesLength);
byteBuffer.asLongBuffer().put(longs);
return byteBuffer.array();
```

[I did an experiment with serializing `float[]` to `byte[]`](https://gitlab.com/janecekpetr/benchmarks/-/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gitlab/janecekpetr/benchmark/FloatSerializationBenchmark.java) and depending on the required byte order and Java version different methods came out differently, but `ByteBuffer` and `MemorySegment` and `Unsafe` or libraries using them were on top. VarHandles are not very far behind, but they're still loopy.

On OpenJDK 17 using G1, on my MBP 16" 2019, the results were:

```
Benchmark             (size)  Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units

beByteBuffer             512  avgt    5    193.351 ±   21.366  ns/op
beByteBufferWrap         512  avgt    5    197.477 ±   43.743  ns/op
beDataOutputStream       512  avgt    5   1590.887 ±   60.744  ns/op
beKryo                   512  avgt    5    861.624 ±   11.927  ns/op
beManualUnpacking        512  avgt    5    861.573 ±   10.108  ns/op
beObjectOutputStream     512  avgt    5   2168.386 ±   12.950  ns/op
beVarHandle              512  avgt    5    225.611 ±    1.839  ns/op

leByteBuffer             512  avgt    5    155.345 ±    1.229  ns/op
leByteBufferWrap         512  avgt    5    154.523 ±    0.853  ns/op
leDataOutputStream       512  avgt    5  55414.147 ± 9390.669  ns/op
leKryoUnsafe             512  avgt    5    156.019 ±   18.235  ns/op
leManualUnpacking        512  avgt    5    880.687 ±   12.856  ns/op
leMemorySegment          512  avgt    5    148.483 ±    0.897  ns/op
leUnsafeCopyMemory       512  avgt    5    149.107 ±    2.011  ns/op
leVarHandle              512  avgt    5    225.615 ±    1.357  ns/op
```

Note that if you're not on Java 17 yet, your results may be very different! The `ObjectOutputStream` was way slower before Java 17, and [two of the four `*byteBuffer` variants were 2* as slow too](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8264762). Therefore, measure for your particular JVM and JVM config. In general, though, `ByteBuffer` or `MemorySegment` is the way to go going forward.

Comment: @Holger Aha, sorry, in that case that was indeed misleading. I DID measure older versions, reported a bug in the ByteBuffer code and it was fixed in Java 17. I reworded the answer a little right now and added the link to the bug.

Comment: Great addition. Very good to know.

Comment: But if I read correctly, putting a single value like `byteBuffer.putLong(…)` was not affected?

Comment: The bug's description is a little messy, sorry about that. I actually reported it as two different bugs, and the engineer processing it mushed them together, so it's slightly confusing. I did *not* measure single `putLong()` calls as I was specifically interested in reinterpreting whole arrays. The bug was in the JVM not using an internal `copyMemory` mechanism for the batch method, but I do not know how the put-single thing works. Feel free to take a look at the benchmarking code and try to add more options.